# MONGODB updateMany using aggregation pipeline and $lookups

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates, aggregation

I have to update the column "AcquireMerchant.Gateway" from Merchants collection but to get the exact amount of records that I have to update it needs to do two lookups with Banks collection and Institution collection.

This is the query that im working on but doesnt work.

The problem is when it execute the forEach I got this error "cannot compare to undefined". The aggregation works perfect

```js
db.getCollection("Merchants_INFRADB1230").aggregate( 
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "Merchants_INFRADB1230": "$$ROOT",
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "as": "Bancos",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "from": "Bancos",
      "localField": "Merchants_INFRADB1230.SellingBankId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$Bancos",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "as": "Instituciones",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "from": "Instituciones",
      "localField": "Bancos.InstitucionesId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$Instituciones",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "Instituciones.GlobalId": "4fb8bc86af95",
      "Merchants_INFRADB1230.AcquireMerchant.Gateway": "Update1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Instituciones.GlobalId": 1,
      "Merchants_INFRADB1230.AcquireMerchant.Gateway": 1,
      "Merchants_INFRADB1230.MID": 1
    }
  }
]).forEach(doc => db.Merchants_INFRADB1230.updateMany(
       { _id: doc._id },
       { $set: { "Merchants_INFRADB1230.AcquireMerchant.Gateway": "Update2"}}));
```

Comment: the result of the aggregate is the one that you need,where the problem occurs? its hard someone to help if we dont have the data, maybe go step by step and see where the problem happens, and if you find it, if you can send some sample data, and the desired output

Comment: The problem is when it execute the forEach I got this error "cannot compare to undefined". The aggregation works perfect

Comment: check this  `db.Merchants_INFRADB1230` its a collection? why you do it differently above?  how about trying `db.getCollection("Merchants_INFRADB1230")` , also check the `doc._id` to be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation returns documents with 3 fields (you explicitly removed _id):

```
"Institutions.GlobalId"
"Merchants_INFRADB1230.AcquireMerchant.Gateway"
"Merchants_INFRADB1230.MID"
```

So in the `forEach`, the `doc` object will have only those fields, and `doc._id` will be undefined, which would make the filter `{_id:doc._id}` not match anything, if it were allowed to be undefined.

The field `"Merchants_INFRADB1230"` was created in the aggregation, and so doesn't exist in the documents in the collection, so the update operation should probably be referring to the field as it exists in those documents:

```
{ $set: { "AcquireMerchant.Gateway": "Update2"}}
```

Comment: You are right I removed the _id! It was a mistake haha! But the "Merchants_INFRADB1230" is not a field its the name of the collection but you are also right it doesnt do anything I was using it like that because in the aggregation with the lookups I ussually have to call the full name (collection and field). The query is now running because it to loop through 50000 records.

Comment: It worked adding the _id and removing the "Merchants_INFRADB1230" from the forEach